# How to delete top "n" rows using sqlite3 in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

Is there an efficient way to delete the top "n" rows of a table in an SQLite database using sqlite3?

**USE CASE:**
--> I need to keep rolling timeseries data in table. To do this, I am fetching `n` new data points regularly and appending it to the table. However, to keep the table updated and a constant size (in terms of number of rows), I need to trim the table by removing the top `n` rows of data.

```
DELETE TOP(n) FROM <table_name>
```

looked promising, but it appears to be unsupported by sqlite3.
Below for example:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("testDB.db")

table_name = "test_table"

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("DELETE TOP(2500) FROM test_table")

conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

The following error is raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_db.py", line 9, in <module>
    c.execute("DELETE TOP(10) FROM test_table")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "TOP": syntax error
```

The only work around I've seen is to use `c.executemany` instead of `c.execute` but this would require specifying the exact dates to delete which is much more cumbersome than it needs to be.

Comment: First of all, even if SQLite supported delete with `TOP`, it would make no sense without an `ORDER BY` clause.  So, you should tell us what is the ordering here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Actually, sqlite **does** support a `DELETE FROM yourtable ORDER BY term LIMIT n` syntax, *if* [it was built from original source (Not the distributed amalgamation sqlite3.c file) and compiled with a specific option](https://sqlite.org/lang_delete.html#optional_limit_and_order_by_clauses). Doing this is easy if you're using a language like C or C++, but loading a custom sqlite3 library in languages like Python is more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite supports this, but not out of the box.

You first have to create a custom sqlite3.c amalgamation file from the master source tree and compile it with the C preprocessor macro [`SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT`](https://sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_update_delete_limit) defined (By running `./configure --enable-update-limit; make`), then put the resulting shared library where Python will load it instead of whatever version it would otherwise use (This is the hard part compared to using it in C or C++, where you can just add a custom `sqlite3.c` to the project source files instead of using a library).

Once all that's done and you're successfully using your own custom sqlite3 library from Python, you can do

```sql
DELETE FROM test_table LIMIT 10
```

which will delete 10 unspecified rows. To control *which* rows to delete, you need an `ORDER BY` clause:

```sql
DELETE FROM test_table ORDER BY foo LIMIT 10
```

See [the documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_delete.html#optional_limit_and_order_by_clauses) for details.

I suspect most people would give up on this as too complicated and just first find the [rowids](https://sqlite.org/rowidtable.html) (Or other primary/unique key) of the rows they want to delete, and then delete them.

Answer (score -4):

There is no way to delete a specific row as far as I know.
You need to drop the table and add it again.

So basically If i had to do it I would fetch the whole table store it in a variable and would remove the part I don't need. Then I will drop the table and create the same table again and then I will input the rest of the data.

Comment: `DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE expression-that-matches-only-the-row-to-delete`

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.